# How to check if a field/attribute is null and blank in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

My payment attribute has a ForeignKey relation. In my accounts.html, I want to show users if they have paid for their orders. So I was trying it like this:

```
{% if order.payment is null or blank %}
    <td> x</td>
{% else %}
    <td> Yes</td>
{% endif %}
```

But it didn't work out. What is the proper code for this?

My orders.models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank= True, null=True)
```

My accounts.html:

```
{% for order in user.order_set.all %}
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
          <td>{{ order.order_id }}</td>
            {% if order.payment is null or blank %}
              <td> x</td>
            {% else %}
              <td> Yes</td>
            {% endif %}
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `blank=True` means you are not required to fill this in in a form, so a field value can not be blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `{% if not order.payment %}`, and I'm pretty sure you can also use `{% if not order.payment.exists %}`, or `{% if order.payment is None %}`

Answer (score 3):

blank is not the state of a field. If a field is blank, then it means that no value is required to be passed. The for example a default value is used.

You can check if a value is `NULL` by checking if the value `is None`:

```
{% if order.payment is None %}
    …
{% endif %}
```